# How to create an Access report from a query using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, automation, report

Let me explain what trying to do. I have a vb.net form linked with an access database. The form let you make a query and search the database. Now I want to put the option to print a report from the same query.

This it what my form look like:

[image]

1. I want to let the user chose what he want to see in the report
2. Create a report from the query
3. Be able to preview the report
4. Print it

   I could not found anywhere how to create report using a specific query.

**What I was able to do**:

1. I was able to print a report that has already been created in access using this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317113/en-us?p=1).
2. I was able to print show the results of the query in an excel sheet.

---

This is the part of my code where I connect to the database and show the results in excel

```
    ' Connect to the database and send the query
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim MaxRows As Integer

    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\docs-management.mdb"
        con.Open()

        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)

        da.Fill(ds, "DocList")

        ' Discover if there's a successful search
        MaxRows = ds.Tables("DocList").Rows.Count

        If MaxRows = 0 Then
            MsgBox("No documents were found using this filter.")
            con.Close()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox As String
        Dim QuestionToMessageBox As String

        QuestionToMessageBox = MaxRows & " Document(s) have been found and will be put into an excel spreadsheet." & _
        vbCrLf & "Would you like to continue?"

        YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = MsgBox(QuestionToMessageBox, vbYesNo, "Narrowing your search")

        If YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
        End If

        Dim oExcel As Object
        Dim oBook As Object
        Dim oSheet As Object
        oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        oExcel.Visible = True
        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
        oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)



        'Transfer the data to Excel
        For columns = 0 To ds.Tables("DocList").Columns.Count - 1
            oSheet.Cells(1, columns + 1) = ds.Tables("DocList").Columns(columns).ColumnName
        Next
        oSheet.Rows("1:1").Font.Bold = True
        For col = 0 To ds.Tables("DocList").Columns.Count - 1
            For row = 0 To ds.Tables("DocList").Rows.Count - 1
                oSheet.Cells(row + 2, col + 1) = ds.Tables("DocList").Rows(row).ItemArray(col)
                ' This is where we make hyperlinks out of the file locations
                If ds.Tables("DocList").Columns(col).ToString = "File_Location" Then
                    oSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=oSheet.Cells(row + 2, col + 1), Address:=ds.Tables("DocList").Rows(row).ItemArray(col), TextToDisplay:=ds.Tables("DocList").Rows(row).ItemArray(col))
                End If
            Next
        Next

        con.Close()

    Catch
        MsgBox("An error has been generated while contacting or transfering data from the database.")
    End Try
```

Comment: Could you use the Primary Interop Assemblies to manipulate the excel sheet and print it?

Comment: Probably, could you give me more information about this and how to get started.

Comment: Can you post your code where you are getting the data from access? It would be good to have a starting point.

Comment: @S.AdamNissley I added some code, this can become complex very fast so let me know if you need more code or some explanation

Comment: you said in your question that you could not create report using a specific query. Aren't you using a query in this line: (da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(**sql**, con))?

Comment: Yes I don't want to just show the table in excel, I want to print it as a report so anyone can understand it

Comment: Okay. I'm at a loss here. You have all the tools in place to:
1) Let the user choose what to include in the report.
2) Create a query to match the required data
3) Build a report in excel - and you already have the application object visible, so the user can see it onscreen.
The only thing I don't see is 'oSheet.PrintPreview'

Comment: How do I make a report in excel?

Comment: It might help to add a reference to your project to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll. After that change the way you set up your Excel/Workbook/Worksheet objects to something like this:  <br/>
`Dim oExcel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application  Dim oBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook  Dim oSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet`  That should help by giving you some intellisense to work with. Create a loop to go through the data returned from your db and arrange it on the sheet or sheets using the methods in the worksheet.

Comment: Thank you for you reply, I will give it a try and give you some feedback. If you want you can put it as an answer this way I can accept it and mark this question as answered if this work for me?

Comment: I'll wait for feedback. Once you are in good shape, I can post answer code. :)

Comment: I've never used Interop before so I will need to do some research to truly understand how to make it work. I tried with the loop I already had but the data could not be transferred from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an some example code that uses an `OleDbConnection` and `Interop.Excel` to generate a payroll report. I think it is relevant here because the rows returned may or may not have values for all columns. The Report is built in Excel dynamically, omitting the columns that have no value.

```
Private Sub PayGrid_Report()
    'PayGrid Report

    If MessageBox.Show("Did you select a payperiod?",
                       "Just checking...",
                       MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                       MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then Exit Sub

    Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xl As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

    'Create a save file dialog
    Dim SaveFileDialog1 As SaveFileDialog
    With SaveFileDialog1
        .Filter = "Excel Workbooks|*.xlsx"
        .AddExtension = True
        .RestoreDirectory = True
        .Title = "Save Report"
        .OverwritePrompt = True
    End With

    'Ask the user where to save the file.
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() <> System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then Exit Sub
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor 'spin the cursor so the user doesn't think it "froze"

    'Set up the connection to the database
    Dim dbConn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Valid Connection String Here")
    dbConn.Open()
    Dim dbComm As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
    With dbComm
        .Connection = dbConn
        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        .CommandText = "PayrollFunctions"
        .Parameters.Add("PayPeriod", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "2015P06" 'usually get a value from the form
        .Parameters.Add("OutputType", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 4 'usually get a value from the form
    End With

    'start a data reader
    Dim r As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = dbComm.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

    Dim rownum As Int32 = 0 'the row to write to in Excel
    Dim t As Int32 'Top of each "report item" - used for formatting
    Dim b As Int32 'Bottom of each "report item" - used for formatting

    xl.Visible = True 'show Excel so the user can see the report building
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Add() 'add a workbook to Excel
    ws = wb.Sheets.Add 'add a sheet to the workbook
    ws.Name = "PayGrid_Report" 'name the sheet

    While r.Read()
        rownum += 2
        t = rownum
        ws.Cells(rownum, 2) = r("EmployeeID")
        ws.Cells(rownum, 3) = r("EmployeeName")
        ws.Cells(rownum, 4) = r("PayrollDepartment")
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(rownum, 2), ws.Cells(rownum, 4)).Font.Bold = True

        If r("RegularHours") > 0 Then
            rownum += 1
            b = rownum
            ws.Cells(rownum, 5) = "Regular Hours:"
            ws.Cells(rownum, 6) = r("RegularHours")
            ws.Cells(rownum, 7) = "@"
            ws.Cells(rownum, 8) = r("RateReg")
            ws.Cells(rownum, 9) = "="
            ws.Cells(rownum, 10) = r("RegDollars")
        End If

        If r("OTHours") > 0 Then
            rownum += 1
            b = rownum
            ws.Cells(rownum, 5) = "Overtime Hours:"
            ws.Cells(rownum, 6) = r("OTHours")
            ws.Cells(rownum, 7) = "@"
            ws.Cells(rownum, 8) = r("RateOT")
            ws.Cells(rownum, 9) = "="
            ws.Cells(rownum, 10) = r("OTDollars")
        End If

        If r("LeaveHours") > 0 Then
            rownum += 1
            b = rownum
            ws.Cells(rownum, 5) = "Vacation Hours:"
            ws.Cells(rownum, 6) = r("LeaveHours")
            ws.Cells(rownum, 7) = "@"
            ws.Cells(rownum, 8) = r("RateVac")
            ws.Cells(rownum, 9) = "="
            ws.Cells(rownum, 10) = r("LeaveDollars")
        End If

        If r("HolidayHours") > 0 Then
            rownum += 1
            b = rownum
            ws.Cells(rownum, 5) = "Holiday Hours:"
            ws.Cells(rownum, 6) = r("HolidayHours")
            ws.Cells(rownum, 7) = "@"
            ws.Cells(rownum, 8) = r("RateHol")
            ws.Cells(rownum, 9) = "="
            ws.Cells(rownum, 10) = r("HolidayDollars")
        End If

        If r("OtherHours") > 0 Then
            If r("RateOtherBas") > 0 Then
                rownum += 1
                b = rownum
                ws.Cells(rownum, 5) = "Other Hours:"
                ws.Cells(rownum, 6) = r("OtherHours")
                ws.Cells(rownum, 7) = "@"
                ws.Cells(rownum, 8) = r("RateOtherBas")
                ws.Cells(rownum, 9) = "="
                ws.Cells(rownum, 10) = r("OtherBaseDollars")
            End If

            If r("RateOtherHol") > 0 Then
                rownum += 1
                b = rownum
                ws.Cells(rownum, 5) = "Other Holiday:"
                ws.Cells(rownum, 6) = r("OtherHours")
                ws.Cells(rownum, 7) = "@"
                ws.Cells(rownum, 8) = r("RateOtherHol")
                ws.Cells(rownum, 9) = "="
                ws.Cells(rownum, 10) = r("OtherHolDollars")
            End If

            If r("RateOtherVac") > 0 Then
                rownum += 1
                b = rownum
                ws.Cells(rownum, 5) = "Other Vacation:"
                ws.Cells(rownum, 6) = r("OtherHours")
                ws.Cells(rownum, 7) = "@"
                ws.Cells(rownum, 8) = r("RateOtherVac")
                ws.Cells(rownum, 9) = "="
                ws.Cells(rownum, 10) = r("OtherVacDollars")
            End If

            If r("RateOtherBen") > 0 Then
                rownum += 1
                b = rownum
                ws.Cells(rownum, 5) = "Other Benefits:"
                ws.Cells(rownum, 6) = r("OtherHours")
                ws.Cells(rownum, 7) = "@"
                ws.Cells(rownum, 8) = r("RateOtherBen")
                ws.Cells(rownum, 9) = "="
                ws.Cells(rownum, 10) = r("OtherBenDollars")
            End If
        End If 'If r("OtherHours") > 0

        rownum += 1
        b = rownum
        ws.Cells(rownum, 5) = "Total:"
        ws.Cells(rownum, 6) = r("TotalHours")
        ws.Cells(rownum, 10) = r("TotalDollars")
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(rownum, 5), ws.Cells(rownum, 10)).Font.Bold = True

        'create border around report item
        Dim LS As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        Dim BW As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBorderWeight = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin
        With ws.Range(ws.Cells(t, 2), ws.Cells(b, 10))
            .Borders(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = LS
            .Borders(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop).Weight = BW
            .Borders(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = LS
            .Borders(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom).Weight = BW
            .Borders(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = LS
            .Borders(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft).Weight = BW
            .Borders(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = LS
            .Borders(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight).Weight = BW
        End With

    End While
    r.Close()

    ws.Columns.AutoFit()
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(1, 1)).ColumnWidth = 0.42

    'Format the page setup
    ws.PageSetup.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlPortrait
    ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
    ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 99
    ws.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "Paygrid Report"
    ws.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "Pay Period 06"
    ws.PageSetup.RightHeader = "Page &P of &N"
    ws.PageSetup.LeftFooter = "Generated " & Today.ToShortDateString

    wb.SaveAs(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    wb.Close()
    xl.Quit()

    Dim psi As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    psi.FileName = "excel"
    psi.Arguments = """" & SaveFileDialog1.FileName & """"
    Dim proc As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi)

    Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it's working. I just need to change your code to fit my program.